# Use jQuery to check and see if div element is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

Below is the code I'm using to place a `blur` event on a text box in my ASP MVC 3 view. The code works fine if `#MailingState` is empty, however it cannot tell if `#channelName` is empty.

For example, if `#channelName` is empty but `#MailingState` is not, then when I place a value in `#MailingZip` the `getDrmTerritory` Ajax call is fired off every time.

Here is the jQuery

```
    $('#MailingZip').blur(function () {
        if ($('#AlignmentM').is(':checked')) {
            if ($('#MailingState').val() != "" && $('#channelName').html() != "") {
                getDrmTerritory($('#MailingZip').val(), $('#MailingState').val(), $('#channelName').html());
            }
        }
    });
```

and here is the HTML for the `#channelName` segment it is checking

```
    <div id="channelName" class="M-display-field">
        @*this will be updated via ajax from Market Segment *@
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Channel, new { style = "margin-left: 300px;" } )
    </div>
```

The section mentioned in the comments is updated via another jQuery method that looks like this

```
function ChangeChannel() {
    //this function called if Market Segment changes, to update the channel
    var pendistcode = document.getElementById('Pendist');
    if (pendistcode == null) alert('Error: Cannot find Market Segment control');
    //alert('!pendistcode value is ' + pendistcode.value);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/AgentTransmission/GetChannel/',
        data: { pendist: pendistcode.value },
        success: function (data) {
            //                alert("success: " + data);
            $('#channelName').html(data);
            $('#Channel').val(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("failure to obtain Channel name");
        }
    });

    CheckTerritory('channel');

} //end ChangeChannel
```

That jQuery method (`ChangeChannel`) appends text to the channelName `div` which, when rendered with a value in it, looks like this

[image]

Here is the HTML you get when you inspect the `Life Sales` from that picture

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put in an `alert` statment to find out `channelName`'s length and it came back with 35, so there must obviously be some white space that gets rendered each time. I had to change the statement to the following to `trim` out the whitespace and add the variable to the condition.

```
            var channel = $.trim($('#channelName').html());
            if ($('#MailingState').val() != "" && channel != "")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if `#channelName` is empty or not like this:

```
if ( $('#channelName').is(':empty') )
```

and combine with your code like this:

```
if ($('#MailingState').val() != "" && !$('#channelName').is(':empty'))
```

Comment: Using the `&& !$('#channelName').is(':empty')` I cannot get the Ajax to fire whether or not there is a value in `channelName`